# How many quotes to put around a formula that is sending an empty "" string

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a formula that I am sending to a cell in the worksheet. The formula is:

```
=IF($V6>0,IF($G6>$S6,($S6-$H6)*$K6+$Y6,($G6-$H6)*$K6+$Y6),"")
```

To send it, I am using the following statement, where the variable "ir" stands for inserted row where the formula needs to go, like this:

```
Cells(ir, "O").Formula = "=IF($G" & ir & ">$S" & ir & ",($S" & ir & "-$H" & ir & ")*$K" & ir & "+$Y" & ir & ",($G" & ir & "-$H" & ir & ")*$K" & ir & "+$Y" & ir & ")," & """ "")"""
```

I think the problem is with the quotes around the empty string at the end ("").

If I enclose it in double quotes, I get a syntax error. If I enclose it in triple quotes, I get an "application-defined or object-defined error".
Is there an easy solution?

Can I use NIL for the empty string?

Other simpler formulas run great. For example, this one:

```
Cells(ir, "N").Formula = "= $L" & ir & "- $M" & ir
```

Comment: you have too many entries.  You have one calc for true and another for false, why do you need the `," & """ "")"""` part.  Just use: `Cells(ir, "O").Formula = "=IF($G" & ir & ">$S" & ir & ",($S" & ir & "-$H" & ir & ")*$K" & ir & "+$Y" & ir & ",($G" & ir & "-$H" & ir & ")*$K" & ir & "+$Y" & ir & ")"`

Comment: You are right Scott, I forgot that when this formula was in the sheet as an Excel formula , I ran an extra check so it would remain blank while there were no entries in another column, then when I transferred it into VBA I removed the first IF but did not remove the end of it. Wow , you have a sharp eye, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[konalion has already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70399681/how-many-quotes-to-put-around-a-formula-that-is-sending-an-empty-string/70400136#70400136) how to pad the double quotes. Also if your formula is constant then you can also try this:

```
Private Const MyFormula As String = _
"=IF($V|>0,IF($G|>$S|,($S|-$H|)*$K|+$Y|,($G|-$H|)*$K|+$Y|),"""") "
```

And then use:

```
Cells(ir, "O").Formula = Replace(MyFormula, "|", ir)
```

Comment: Hi Siddharth , yours worked great, you added that extra if, that I had in the original formula and mistakenly left out later, as Scott pointed out. What I like about your solution is that in the constant line, I can see clearly what the formula is , and then just replace the pipe sign with my variable, As you can see , I am fairly new to this, and learning VBA at 65 I guess is a lot harder than when I was learning programming in high school using FORTRAN. 

Answer (score 4):

If your intention was to use the null string -
try this, which removes the extra external quotes:

```
Cells(ir, "O").Formula = "=IF($G" & ir & ">$S" & ir & ",($S" & ir & "-$H" & ir & ")*$K" & ir & "+$Y" & ir & ",($G" & ir & "-$H" & ir & ")*$K" & ir & "+$Y" & ir & ")," & """ "")"
```

Try this, which removes the extra internal and external quotes:

```
Cells(ir, "O").Formula = "=IF($G" & ir & ">$S" & ir & ",($S" & ir & "-$H" & ir & ")*$K" & ir & "+$Y" & ir & ",($G" & ir & "-$H" & ir & ")*$K" & ir & "+$Y" & ir & ")," & "" ")"
```

If your intention was to use empty string -
try this, which removes the extra external quotes:

```
Cells(ir, "O").Formula = "=IF($G" & ir & ">$S" & ir & ",($S" & ir & "-$H" & ir & ")*$K" & ir & "+$Y" & ir & ",($G" & ir & "-$H" & ir & ")*$K" & ir & "+$Y" & ir & ")," & """"")"
```

Try this, which removes the extra internal and external quotes:

```
Cells(ir, "O").Formula = "=IF($G" & ir & ">$S" & ir & ",($S" & ir & "-$H" & ir & ")*$K" & ir & "+$Y" & ir & ",($G" & ir & "-$H" & ir & ")*$K" & ir & "+$Y" & ir & ")," & """)"
```

Or maybe you had it right to begin with, and just needed to delete the space to keep it an empty sting:

```
Cells(ir, "O").Formula = "=IF($G" & ir & ">$S" & ir & ",($S" & ir & "-$H" & ir & ")*$K" & ir & "+$Y" & ir & ",($G" & ir & "-$H" & ir & ")*$K" & ir & "+$Y" & ir & ")," & """"")"""
```

Comment: wow, thank you for the time investment, this is great, really appreciate it.

Comment: @Adam B Which worked?

Comment: Nicely explained

Comment: Hi konalion, I have  tried them all , but they did not work  because as Scott pointed out,  I had too many entries, please see my comment above, However I will keep them all in my back pocket for when I do need a blank at the end.  I'm sure one of them will do the trick. Thank you again for taking the time!