# Translate formula quotation marks incl. replacements into VBA-readable formulae

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

**Translate formula quotation marks incl. replacements into VBA-readable formulae**

I was inspired to write this post by the recent question of
[formula substitution using a constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70399681/how-many-quotes-to-put-around-a-formula-that-is-sending-an-empty-string).
At the same time, the frequent problem emerged that quotation marks
**within** a formula string should be replaced by **double** *quotation marks* in order
to make them readable in VBA.

**Practical use case**

A practical use case is to copy a table formula directly from a SO website
and "translate" it into a string-readable format.

But how is this supposed to be done with VBA means, since the **direct** input of
such an incomplete formula string in a procedure code without **manually**
added double quotation marks would immediately lead to an error?

Another feature would be to make replacements at certain points *within*
a formula template, for example with a constant or even with several
numerically identifiable markers.

I found a quick & dirty solution (without error handling) by analyzing a `FormulaContainer` procedure containing
exclusively outcommented formulae as these would allow any prior direct code input.
In order to distinguish them from the usual commentaries,
I decided with a heavy heart to use the `Rem` prefix (i.e. Remark) as an alternative, which we may still be familiar with from ancient Basic times.

*My intention is not to show a perfect solution, but to stimulate further solutions
by demonstrating a possible way.*

**Question**

> Are there other work arounds allowing to copy tabular formulae with quotation marks directly and as possible replacement pattern into VBA procedures?

///////////////////////////////////

**Main function `QuickFormula()`**

References a FormulaContainer procedure containing *exclusively* formulae with `Rem`  prefixes, such as e.g.

```
    Sub FormulaContainer()
    Rem =....
    Rem =....
    End Sub
```

This allows formula inputs with quotation marks similar to tabular cell inputs;
furthermore these inputs may contain string identifiers facilitating wanted replacements.

```
Option Explicit
'Site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70399681/how-many-quotes-to-put-around-a-formula-that-is-sending-an-empty-string
'Auth: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m

Function QuickFormula(ByVal no As Long, ParamArray repl() As Variant) As String
'Purp: - change indicated code line in FormulaContainer to code readable string and
'      - replace enumerated identifiers with given value(s)
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'1) get REMark code line indicated by ordinal argument no
    QuickFormula = getCodeLine("modFormula", "FormulaContainer", no)
'2a)replace "#" identifyer(s) with constant repl value
    If Not IsArray(repl(0)) Then
        QuickFormula = Replace(QuickFormula, "{1}", "#")
        QuickFormula = Replace(QuickFormula, "#", repl(0))
        If Len(QuickFormula) = 0 Then QuickFormula = "Error NA!"
        Debug.Print no & " ~~> " & Chr(34) & QuickFormula & Chr(34)
        Exit Function
    End If
'2b)replace 1-based "{i}" identifiers by ParamArray values
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(repl(0)) To UBound(repl(0))
        QuickFormula = Replace(QuickFormula, "{" & i + 1 & "}", repl(0)(i))
    Next
'3) optional display in immediate window
    Debug.Print no & " ~~> " & Chr(34) & QuickFormula & Chr(34)
End Function
```

**Help function `getCodeLine()`**

Gets a given code line of the indicated procedure

```
Function getCodeLine(ByVal ModuleName As String, ByVal ProcedureName As String, Optional ByVal no As Long = 1) As String
'Purp:  return a code line in given procedure containing "Rem "
'Note:  assumes no line breaks; needs a library reference to
'       "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3"

    Const SEARCH As String = "Rem =", QUOT As String = """"
'1) set project
    Dim VBProj As Object
    Set VBProj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
    If VBProj.Protection = vbext_pp_locked Then Exit Function ' escape locked projects
'2) set component
    Dim VBComp As Object
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents(ModuleName)
    Dim pk As vbext_ProcKind

'3) get no + 3 top code line(s)
    With VBComp.CodeModule
        'a)count procedure header lines
        Dim HeaderCount As Long:  HeaderCount = .ProcBodyLine(ProcedureName, pk) - .ProcStartLine(ProcedureName, pk)
        'b) get procedure code
        Dim codelines
        'codelines = Split(.Lines(.ProcBodyLine(ProcedureName, pk), .ProcCountLines(ProcedureName, pk) - HeaderCount), vbNewLine)
        codelines = Split(.Lines(.ProcBodyLine(ProcedureName, pk), no + 1), vbNewLine)
        'c) filter code lines containing "Rem" entries
        codelines = Filter(codelines, SEARCH, True)
    End With

'4) return (existing) codeline no
    If no - 1 > UBound(codelines) Then Exit Function    ' check existance
    getCodeLine = Replace(Replace(codelines(no - 1), QUOT, String(2, QUOT)), "Rem =", "=")
End Function
```

**Example call**

References all three formulae in the `FormulaContainer` (including an example of a non-existing number):

```
Sub EnterFormula()
    With Sheet1.Range("X1")      ' << change to any wanted target range
        .Offset(1).Formula2 = QuickFormula(1, 6)
        .Offset(2).Formula2 = QuickFormula(2, Array(10, 20, 30))
        'two single argument inputs with same result
        .Offset(3).Formula2 = QuickFormula(3, Array(17))
        .Offset(4).Formula2 = QuickFormula(3, 17)
        'not existing formula number in Rem code container
        .Offset(5).Formula2 = QuickFormula(333, 17)
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Example FormulaContainer**

```
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'Purp: formula container to be adjusted to code readable strings
'Note: Insert only Formulae starting with "Rem "-prefix!
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'      #   identifies constant replacement(s)
'      {i} stands for enumerated replacements {1},{2}..{n}
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Sub FormulaContainer()
Rem =IF($V#>0,IF($G#>$S#,($S#-$H#)*$K#+$Y#,($G#-$H#)*$K#+$Y#),"")
Rem =A{1}*B{3}+C{2}
Rem =A{1}+100
End Sub
```

**Example output in immediate window**

```
    1 ~~> "=IF($V6>0,IF($G6>$S6,($S6-$H6)*$K6+$Y6,($G6-$H6)*$K6+$Y6),"""")"
    2 ~~> "=A10*B30+C20"
    3 ~~> "=A17+100"
    3 ~~> "=A17+100"
  333 ~~> "Error NA!"
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. IMHO what you have is an overkill. I would still prefer to manually pad the double quotes than using a `FormulaContainer`. Also the code that you have given requires the user to trust access to the VBA project object model. Lot of corporate users may not have enough Rights to turn that feature on.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, totally agree with ..and that's exactly why I asked this question to encourage other approaches, preferrable as simple as possible :-) @SiddharthRout

Answer (score 0):

**Keep it simple stupid**

Assuming either the currently selected cell formula or a textbox input, a simple Userform might act as a formula translator into a line of VBA code:

**Basic Userform code**

Needed: TextBox1, TextBox2, CommandButton1

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Purp: Redouble inside quotation marks
    Const Quot As String = """"
    Dim assignTo As String
    assignTo = "ws.Range(""" & Selection.Address(False, False) & """).Formula2 = "
    Me.TextBox2.Text = assignTo & Quot & Replace(Me.TextBox1.Text, Quot, String(2, Quot)) & Quot
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Purp: assume active formula as wanted input
    Me.TextBox1 = Selection.Formula2
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Layout()
'Purp: example layout textboxes
'a) define textboxes
    Dim textboxes() As String
    textboxes = Split("Textbox1,Textbox2", ",")
'b) format
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(textboxes)
    With Me.Controls(textboxes(i))
        .Font.Name = "Courier New"
        .Font.Size = 12
        .MultiLine = True
        .EnterKeyBehavior = True
    End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Possible extensions**
Of course you might add an insertion routine (inserting e.g. {} brackets) as well as some replacement procedures like in my workaround above.

Just for fun, a basic insertion routine here:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
'Purp: Insert brackets {}
    With Me.TextBox1
        .SetFocus
        If InsertAtCursor("{}", Me.TextBox1) Then
            .SelStart = .SelStart - 1
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Public Function InsertAtCursor(s As String, ctrl As MSForms.Control, Optional ErrMsg As String) As Boolean
'Purpose:   Insert the characters at the cursor in the active control.
'Site:      http://allenbrowne.com/func-InsertChar.html
'Return:    True if characters were inserted.
'Arguments: s = the character(s) you want inserted at the cursor.
'           ErrMsg = string to append any error messages to.
'Note:      Control must have focus.
    On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    Dim prior  As String                      'Text before the cursor.
    Dim after  As String                      'Text after the cursor.
    Dim cnt    As Long                        'Number of characters
    Dim iSelStart As Long                        'Where cursor is.
    Dim txt    As String                      'text with LineFeeds only
    
    If s <> vbNullString Then
        With ctrl                         ' --> UserForm Control
              
            txt = Replace(.Text, vbCrLf, vbLf) '     LineFeeds only (MultiLine)
            If .Enabled And Not .Locked Then
                cnt = Len(txt)             '     Zählung ohne vbCr's !
                
                'SelStart can't cope with more than 32k characters.
                If cnt <= 32767& - Len(s) Then
                    'Remember characters before cursor.
                    iSelStart = .SelStart
                    If iSelStart > 1 Then
                        prior = Left$(txt, iSelStart)
                    End If
                    'Remember characters after selection.
                    If iSelStart + .SelLength < cnt Then
                        after = Mid$(txt, iSelStart + .SelLength + 1) ' OP:2
                    End If
                    'Assign prior characters, new ones, and later ones.
                    .value = prior & s & after
                    'Put the cursor back where it as, after the new ones.
                    .SelStart = iSelStart + Len(s)
                    'Return True on success
                    InsertAtCursor = True
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
    
Exit_Handler:
    Exit Function
    
Err_Handler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 438&, 2135&, 2144&                      'Object doesn't support this property. Property is read-only. Wrong data type.
        ErrMsg = ErrMsg & "You cannot insert text here." & vbCrLf
    Case 2474&, 2185&                            'No active control. Control doesn't have focus.
        ErrMsg = ErrMsg & "Cannot determine which control to insert the characters into." & vbCrLf
    Case Else
        ErrMsg = ErrMsg & "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & vbCrLf
    End Select
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function
```

[image: userform example]